# Не работает русский язык VS c++ с string вне функции main

Tags: c++, строки, ifstream

Считываю объект с двумя строками из текстового файла и при выводе в консоль выдает иероглифы. Когда я делал это в main, все было нормально, но после переноса в другой файл русский перестал работать. Строковые литералы выводит нормально, проблема только с string. С английским языком все корректно работает.

```
//имя.cpp
void showCatalog()
{
ifstream in(FILE_FLOWERS);

Flower* flower = new Flower;
int number = 1;

system("cls");
cout << "Esc) ВЫЙТИ ИЗ КАТАЛОГА" << endl;
while (!in.eof())
{
    flower->read(in);
    cout << number << ")____________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "Название цветка: " << flower->getName() << endl;
    cout << "Цвет: " << flower->getColor() << endl;
    cout << "Длина: " << flower->getLength() << endl;
    cout << "Цена: " << flower->getPrice() << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
    number++;
    }

    in.close();
    delete flower;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вписать `SetConsoleCP(1251) SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` и подключить `#include <Windows.h>`;
А также в свойствах консоли укажите шрифт "Lucida Console".